# Mesos slaves on windows server 2012r2, what are my options?

Tags: windows, mesos

I have a cluster of machines running windows server 2012R2.
I would like to manage them with mesos.
To the best of my knowledge, microsoft is actively contributing to mesos (DC/OS) and will support containers natively on windows server 2016. Furthermore, it looks like there is another type of container flavour using hyper-v.

I can run my mesos masters on linux hosts. However I need my slaves on windows server 2012R2 hosts. It is not clear to me which technologies are already available (and **production-ready**) for my windows server version.

What are my options to use mesos to manage the resources of my windows server machines ?

- Is the mesos-agent for windows (server 2012 R2) production ready ?
- Can I use containers (hyper-v or docker) ? If not, is the resource isolation working in Windows (in linux you can use cgroups) ?
- Can I run any framework I like or there are some not compatible with windows ?

Comment: Mesos can't "manage" your Windows servers. The Mesos agents would just offer their resources to the Mesos masters

Comment: Are you asking what containerization options do you have?

Comment: My question is more general, containers and the general state of mesos on windows, is it production ready ? has the same features as in linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Mesos version 1.0.0 was recently released that allows you to run the slave and launcher on windows. Not the master unfortunately. Its still Linux, but it doesn't really ever need to be Windows? The slave was the important bit for bringing Windows machines into the Mesos domain.

I've just been investigating using the Mesos-Slave on windows.  Pleased to say that it appears to be working OK (this opinion is subject to change as I'm still testing it).  Production ready is something any business would have to decide for themselves.

Mesos have always had their own isolation technology, interestingly they have redone their own containerizer implementation and this now takes a number of container image formats, so you can use your Docker images as well as a few others, so this is going to suit you. There was a good presentation on this at MesosCon  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHUngcGgzVM

Docker's been stealing the show to some extent. But if you use Mesos-Agent, Windows 2016 and its container technology (Docker) isn't needed and therefore it should run on Windows 2012. I've not got around to trying this yet but its definitely a test worth trying, it opens up deployment options. Anyone?

One thing to remember about containers, they are not VM's.  The guest image must be a derivative of the hosts OS, you can't run a Linux image on a Windows machine.  Causing me a headache, I can't use servernano at the moment, so my image sizes are 4Gb+, the initial deploy time is hours.